# Substitution of complex power series, example of my book

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm reading this example of my book.
It is in dutch, but I think it is clear even if you don't understand the words.

[image: http://snag.gy/uhZSZ.jpg]

There are two things I don't understand:

1. Why does the sum begin with $n=1$ here ? I learned that it should begin with $n=0$.
2. In the last equality, I get confused, I would think it should be $-n!$.

Comment: Ths sum starts at $n=0$. Typo in your book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point 1.: You are right, that is an error, $e^w = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{w^n}{n!}$.

Point 2.: You are right, that is an error, $e^{1/z} = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{0} \dfrac{z^n}{(-n)!}$.